# Multithreaded programming for CPUs with E/P cores on Alder Lake architecture

Tags: parallel-processing

This is more a conceptual/high level question rather than a language specific one.

In terms of writing software for high performance applications that will use multiple threads, would it be advisable to manually check for and only allocate threads to P cores, or rather just simply allocate threads as they were done before Alder Lake, and let the OS scheduler decide where to put them?

To be more specific, my program will be a computer game with separate computationally expensive CPU threads for AI, pathfinding, etc. Ideally I don't want these threads on E cores but I'm wondering if I should be leaving this sort of thing up to the OS to decide instead of ensuring it manually.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably not a good question for SO, and might fit better on https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com, but here goes with a conceptual/high-level answer anyways.

*In terms of writing software for high performance applications* you will get best performance by writing platform-dependent code, that is by writing programs which are informed by, and take advantage of, the particular features of the hardware+o/s+runtime on which the programs are to execute.

The costs of this approach are that the code will, by definition, be less-than-optimal-performancewise on any other platform; and that writing codes to squeeze out every last drop of performance for a particular problem can be quite difficult and time consuming.

Personally (so this might be an opinion, which is something SO doesn't like) I would first write the platform-neutral version of the code and test it.  Only when I was convinced that I couldn't achieve necessary performance (or other) goals would I roll up my sleeves and develop that first version into a platform-dependent version. (Well, I might do this extra work for fun, but you catch my drift).

Later, if you want to move the program to another platform you already have the platform-neutral version to start with.

Comment: Thanks for this answer Mark I like it. Even in terms of writing specifically for a platform, I'm still curious if it's good or bad practice to override the OS scheduler and manually determine if I should put a thread on a P or E core, or let the scheduler decide this? Ideally the scheduler should do a good job but in practice it often doesn't, but this architecture is still new so OS updates may change that. The code will be deployed on client machines not a server so I'd be doing conditional checks if such architecture were present, and only do the P/E core allocations manually if so

Comment: *I'm still curious ...* Sufficiently curious to invest your time into developing the codes?  It's the only way to resolve the question with an authoritative answer.